# Constructing an equilateral triangle with a given segment as a side, using a compass whose radius is less than the length of the segment

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction

Say I have a line segment $AB$. I have a compass that can only create a circle with some random radius $r$ that is less than the length of $AB$. (I also have a straight-edge to create lines of arbitrary length.)

In this case, is there a general method for constructing an equilateral triangle with $AB$ as one side, using only Euclid's 5 postulates and common mathematical notions(ex: if $a=b$ and $b=c$ then $a=c$)?

Comment: Oh, dear! I have misremembered what Euclid's fifth postulate actually said! I have deleted my answer for the time being, as I see if it can be salvaged.

Comment: For clarity's sake, let me confirm: your available tools are (1) a straight-edge and (2) a compass of fixed radius $r$ less than the length of $AB$? Put another way, it seems that, while you are allowed an idealized straight edge of arbitrary length, your compass is restricted to radius $r.$ Is that right?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: Drat.... In that case, I have no intuition whether this is possible.

Answer (score 5):

Start by drawing a point $B'$ on the $AB$ segment, at a distance $r<AB$ from $A$, towards $B$. You know how to construct $C'$ say above $AB$, such that $AB'C'$ is an equilateral triangle with side $r$. Note that $\angle B'AC'=\angle BAC'=60^\circ$. Now repeat the same procedure at point $B$: find $A''$ towards $A$ on $AB$, at distance $r$ from $B$, then construct $C''$ so that the triangle $A''BC''$ is equilateral, with $C''$ on the same side of $AB$ as $C'$. Once again, notice that $\angle A''BC''=\angle ABC''=60^\circ$. Now all you need to do is extend $AC'$ and $BC''$ until they meet at a point $C$. Since two of the angles in the $ABC$ triangle are $60^\circ$, you have an equilateral triangle, with side $AB$.

Comment: But how could we prove this without knowing that the sum of the interior angles of a triangle are 180 degrees? Because without that knowledge we could have only an isosceles triangle.

Comment: You can prove that the sum of angles is $180^\circ$ using Euclid's 5th postulate.

Comment: So the only way to prove that the triangle we constructed is equilateral is to first prove that the sum of angles is $180^\circ$? Or is there another way?

Comment: Not directly from the postulates. I could also do it with similar triangles, but that seems more involved.

Comment: I'm confused by your question.  You know that the interior angles of all triangles is $180$ because that was proven by Euclid very early on.  The fact that you are sitting down with limited materials to do constructions doesn't mean that every thing history has proven in the past is magically revoked for no good reason.

Comment: Ok thank you. The reason for my question is because I learned geometry in school by simply memorizing most of these rules. I've decided to start from scratch by putting myself through a geometry course based on the 5 postulates while trying to answer the questions without any assumed knowledge beyond the course itself. The first theorem in the course is similar to my original question except without the limitation of the radius being less than AB. One of the questions asked how you would construct such a triangle if your compass rusted and was stuck on some distance less than line segment AB.

Comment: Maybe your question is, if we replace the axiom of Euclid that states you may construct a circle of any length with, you may construct circles of only one length, what happens?  In which case I'm not too sure.  I don't think you can do much of anything.

Comment: One thing pretty subtle about Euclids elements and geometric constructions is that these magic tools of compass and straightedges aren't actually for making things; they are for verifying it is okay to assume figures of specific dimensions can exist.  That is you can find of distance of foo, then you know lines of distance foo will always exist in any place and any orientation. "Contructing" was just Euclids way of saying we know they exist.

Comment: It is a different course based around Euclid's 5 postulates. The first theorem in the course covers creating equilateral triangles with a given length AB for one of the sides. As I'm sure you know you can easily do this and prove that the triangle is indeed equilateral by creating circles about each point with a radius = to AB. However, in the course the question was asked if it was possible to construct an equilateral triangle with sides equal to AB with some radius less than the length of AB.

Comment: Clearly in this course you are given adequate tools to prove that the sum of interior angles is $180$ degrees. And it certainly is possible to construct an equilateral triangle of arbitrary size with a rusty compass. The only thing that seems to be in question is whether at this point in the course you have enough results already that the _proof of correctness_ of the construction (as opposed to merely describing it) is already done or can be completed very easily. But maybe this isn't such a good course after all?

Comment: Yes, you need 5th postulate to prove this is an equilateral triangle: think for instance of spherical triangles. Without 5th postulate, you can only assert that triangle $ABC$ is isosceles with base $AB$.

Comment: @David K. It is not a fault of the course but mine. The course is literally just definitions and postulates taken directly from Euclid's elements. However, the theorems are in a different order, I don't know exactly since I never actually read The Elements. This was the first theorem, so I decided that I would not use theorems and proofs that I already know, have not been shown in the course and that would be unlikely to be discovered by a brand new student. In essence, I'm challenging myself to take a path of discovery to new ideas and a deeper understanding of old ones.

Comment: Your approach seems reasonable. The theorems and exercises should build gradually upon previous theorems and exercises. You shouldn't have to draw on later theorems or do a lengthy proof yourself in order to do the exercise after the first theorem. And it seems wrong to assign this exercise without giving you the tools to know _why_ the answer is correct. As far as I can see, you are doing the right things and asking the right questions.

Answer (score 1):

Construct $60^o$ angles at the base:
[image]

or construct a small triangle $\triangle AEG$ with the radius of your compass and then find $C$ as the intersection of the line $AG$ and the line $a$ from the point $B$ parallel to the segment $EG$:

[image]

Comment: This is the same as [Andrei's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3101893/409).